# How to use a specification in a test without Mock

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, nunit, moq

I have a service method and I want to test it. Is it possible to make the specification work without Mock?

I use the following approach for specification (with Unit of Work, Generic Repository and Entity Framework Core):

```
public interface ISpecification<in T>
{
    bool IsSatisfied(T? item);
}

public abstract class ExpressionSpecification<T> : ISpecification<T>
{
    private Func<T?, bool>? _expressionFunc;

    public abstract Expression<Func<T?, bool>> Expression { get; }

    private Func<T?, bool> ExpressionFunc => _expressionFunc ?? (_expressionFunc = Expression.Compile());

    public bool IsSatisfied(T? item)
    {
       return ExpressionFunc(item);
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the specification (the condition here for example is simple, but it can be complex and you don't want to duplicate it in the test):

```
public class IsAgeMoreThenSpecification: ExpressionSpecification<Employee>
{
    private readonly int _age;

    public IsAgeMoreThen(int age) => _age = age;

    public override Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> Expression => x => x.Age > _age;
}
```

The method I want to test is this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>?> GetEmployeesAsync(int age) {
  IEnumerable<Employee>? result = await _uow.Departments
    .GetQuery(/*some other specs*/)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Employees!)
    .Where(_spec.IsAgeMoreThen(age))
    .ToListAsync();

  return result;
}
```

Here is my NUnit test. Mock (Moq framwork) for `GetQuery` returns what is needed. Next, I need to make the `IsAgeMoreThen` specification work without Mock - that is, so that it would actually check the condition. And filter the data. Is it possible?

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyServiceTests
{    
    private Mock<IUnitOfWork> _uowMock;
    private Mock<IEmploeeSpecifications> _employeeSpecMock;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _uowMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        _employeeSpecMock = new Mock<IEmploeeSpecifications>();
    }
    
    [TestCase(35, 2)]
    public async Task GetEmployeesAsync_ReturnsData(int age, int exceptedCount)
    {
        // Arrange
        var query = new[]
        { 
            new Department 
            {
                Employees = new List<Employee>
                { 
                    new Employee { Age = 20 },
                    new Employee { Age = 30 },
                } 
            },
            new Department 
            {
                Employees = new List<Employee>
                { 
                    new Employee { Age = 40 },
                    new Employee { Age = 50 },
                } 
            }
        }.ToAsyncEnumerable();
        
        _uowMock.Setup(x => x.Departments.GetQuery(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Department, bool>>>()))
            .Returns(query)
        
        /* We mock the specification and lose filtering
        _employeeSpecMock.Setup(x => x.IsAgeMoreThen(It.IsAny<int>()).Returns(x => true);
        */
        
        // Act
        IEnumerable<SpentYearlyModel>? actual = await _service!.GetEmployeesAsync(age);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(actual.Count, exceptedCount);
    }
}
```